# How can I figure out why Linenoise is failing to install?

Tags: module, installation, raku

This is on 64-bit Windows 10 Pro with MSVC 2015. This question has a long body because I want to give full information up front, but the actual question is rather straightforward:

*How can I get `panda` to keep the working directory around (like `cpanm`does) after an install failure so I can diagnose what went wrong?*

As you can see from the log below, `linenoise.dll` seems to be created in the right place, but come install time, it is nowhere to be found.

The `.panda-work` directory in `%TEMP%` is gone.

---

I just built [Rakudo](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/) from source by doing

1. `git clone git://github.com/rakudo/rakudo.git`
2. `cd rakudo`
3. `set CFLAGS=/O2 /favor:INTEL64 /Qpar`
4. `perl Configure.pl --gen-moar --gen-nqp --backends=moar --prefix=c:/opt/perl6`
5. `nmake test`
6. `nmake install`
7. `nmake spectest` ← *The number of failures has gone up since the last time I tried this, but that's not related to my question*

Then I installed `panda` by doing:

1. `git clone --recursive git://github.com/tadzik/panda.git`
2. `cd panda`
3. `perl6 bootstrap.pl`

which worked.

Then I did

`panda install Task::Star`

I got a test failure:

```
==> Building NativeHelpers::Blob
==> Testing NativeHelpers::Blob

t/00-trivial.t ..
Dubious, test returned 5 (wstat 1280, 0x500)
Failed 1/1 subtests
```

but I force installed that because I wanted to get to as complete an install as possible as quickly as possible.

So, forging ahead, I hit this:

```
C:\Users\...\Temp> panda install Linenoise
==> Fetching Linenoise
==> Building Linenoise

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c  /nologo /MT /Ox /GL /DNDEBUG  /DWIN32 /DAO_ASSUME_WINDOWS98  /O2 /favor:INTEL64 /Qpar /Folinenoise.obj linenoise.c
linenoise.c
        perl6 -e "mkdir 'resources'; mkdir 'resources/libraries'"
        link /dll /nologo /LTCG  shell32.lib ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib rpcrt4.lib advapi32.lib psapi.lib iphlpapi.lib userenv.lib /out:resources/libraries/libline
noise.dll linenoise.obj
Generating code
Finished generating code
        cl /Foconstant-helper /nologo /MT /Ox /GL /DNDEBUG  /DWIN32 /DAO_ASSUME_WINDOWS98  /O2 /favor:INTEL64 /Qpar constant-helper.c
constant-helper.c
Generating code
Finished generating code
        perl6 fill-constants.pl  lib/Linenoise.pm
==> Testing Linenoise
==> Installing Linenoise
Failed to open file C:\Users\...\Temp\.panda-work\1483278033_1\resources\libraries\linenoise.dll: no such file or directory
  in any  at C:\opt\perl6/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm line 1
  in block  at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\85367160D11E565B2D089507C79BC309215430D6 (Panda::Installer) line 61
  in sub indir at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\24811C576EF8F85E7672B26955C802BB2FC94675 (Panda::Common) line 20
  in method install at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\85367160D11E565B2D089507C79BC309215430D6 (Panda::Installer) line 42
  in method install at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\582CB7486602954A4601BDCE5A0EAC54B05DA58A (Panda) line 190
  in method resolve at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\582CB7486602954A4601BDCE5A0EAC54B05DA58A (Panda) line 263
  in sub MAIN at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\resources\1C71F7B377C6F2C6C4707E3C25016AA25A2926B1 line 20
  in block  at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\resources\1C71F7B377C6F2C6C4707E3C25016AA25A2926B1 line 165

Actually thrown at:
  in method throw at C:\opt\perl6/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm line 1
  in any  at gen/moar/Metamodel.nqp line 3072
  in block  at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\85367160D11E565B2D089507C79BC309215430D6 (Panda::Installer) line 61
  in sub indir at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\24811C576EF8F85E7672B26955C802BB2FC94675 (Panda::Common) line 20
  in method install at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\85367160D11E565B2D089507C79BC309215430D6 (Panda::Installer) line 42
  in method install at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\582CB7486602954A4601BDCE5A0EAC54B05DA58A (Panda) line 190
  in method resolve at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\sources\582CB7486602954A4601BDCE5A0EAC54B05DA58A (Panda) line 263
  in sub MAIN at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\resources\1C71F7B377C6F2C6C4707E3C25016AA25A2926B1 line 20
  in block  at C:\opt\perl6\share\perl6\site\resources\1C71F7B377C6F2C6C4707E3C25016AA25A2926B1 line 165
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Build.pm file for Linenoise is simply not written correctly. They are hard-coding the 'lib' prefix to the library name while also trying to use the platform library name guessing mechanism in another part. If it wants to use `$*VM.platform-library-name` then it needs to generate a file named `linenoise.dll`, *not* `liblinenoise.dll`

I'm also not sure that Linenoise works on windows even if it *did* install.

You should probably be using `zef` instead of `panda`. If you were, you could view the working directory used at `~/.zef/store/p6-linenoise.git`

Comment: Thanks. I am only using `panda` because [How to get Rakudo](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/) only mentions `panda`.

Comment: PR to fix windows install: https://github.com/hoelzro/p6-linenoise/pull/19